# rsyncで名前に漢字を含むファイルの同期に失敗する

Tags: cygwin, rsync

`c:\Documents`の中に、漢字で書いてあるファイルネームがあります。下のスクリプトを実行すると

```
REM Set CYGWIN variable to 'nontsec'. That makes sure that permissions
REM on your windows machine are not updated as a side effect of cygwin
REM operations.
SET CYGWIN=nontsec

rsync -a --delete -v --progress "/cygdrive/c/Documents" "/cygdrive/d/" --log-file="reports.log"
```

`d:\`に該当のファイルがコピーされない。エラーメッセージは

```
2018/03/21 22:04:28 [11148] file has vanished: "/cygdrive/c/Documents/2017.5.12 ????_170515_0001.jpg"
2018/03/21 22:04:28 [11148] file has vanished: "/cygdrive/c/Documents/2017.5.12 ????_170515_0002.jpg"
2018/03/21 22:04:28 [11148] file has vanished: "/cygdrive/c/Documents/2017.5.12 ????_170515_0003.jpg"
2018/03/21 22:04:28 [11148] file has vanished: "/cygdrive/c/Documents/2017.5.12 ????_170515_0004.jpg"
2018/03/21 22:04:28 [11148] file has vanished: "/cygdrive/c/Documents/2017.5.12 ????_170515_0005.jpg"
2018/03/21 22:04:28 [11148] file has vanished: "/cygdrive/c/Documents/2017.5.12 ????_170515_0006.jpg"
```

どうすればいいでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 漢字（2バイト文字=日本語)が含まれていると問答無用で失敗するのでしょうか。失敗するファイルとは別の漢字が含まれるファイル名を作成してみるとどうなりますか。また、Cygwinで実行されているようですが、参考までにWindowsのバージョンも追記しておくとよいかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick : 漢字が含まれていると問答無用で失敗します。

Comment: @cubick :別の漢字もダメです。

Comment: Windows 10 + cygwin64 環境の rsync で試してみましたが日本語ファイルでも正常にコピーされました。(バッチファイルのrsyncのパスを cygwin の rsync コマンドの絶対パスに変更した程度)

Comment: @sa-y : 私のOSは日本語じゃなくて英語です。関係があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

cwRsync 3.1.0の代わりにcwRsync 5.5.0を使って、問題がなくなった。